# 25 degree by 36 degree (oval) LED light beam spread

Tags: lighting, led, recessed-lighting

I have some [Philips PAR20 2700K LEDs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B4TR8VK) in my house. Some are 36 degree, others are 25 degree beams. I was wondering if there is any way to get an oval beam LED light bulb, as in a 36 by 25 degree light pool, or something equivalent to an oval shape (A° x B°). If not directly manufactured, is there some sort of lens I could put in front of a [BR20 flood led lamp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YI5TDZQ) that can achieve this that is fairly thin?

The PAR20 lights are mounted with the [Juno 440 Trim](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EFV6YE) with the [Juno 4-Inch IC New Construction Housing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EG2FU2); yes this combo works, the socket can be unscrewed allowing for a gimbal to work without a whip.